# Disable WPF Material Design Timepicker Hint Text

Tags: wpf, material-design, timepicker

I am using a Material Design `TimePicker` to take some time input. The time picker is working fine. But I have a problem about the style. I want to remove the hint Text from the control which is showing up "select time" by default.

```
control = new MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.TimePicker { Name = "timepicker_" + df.dataName, SelectedTime = null, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };
this.RegisterName("timepicker_" + df.dataName, control);
```

I am creating the control from code behind. The output of these 2 lines is
[image]

I want to remove this hint help text from the time pickermcontrol. from code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `HintAssist.Hint` attached property to `string.Empty` or `null`:

```
control = new MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.TimePicker { Name = "timepicker_" + df.dataName, SelectedTime = null, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center };

MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.HintAssist.SetHint(control, string.Empty);
```